# python multiprocess map for lines in a file

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Could anyone tell me why the following doesnt generate any output?

```
python mycode.py< file.txt
```

mycode.py is

```
import sys, time, multiprocessing
def work(l):
  time.sleep(len(l))    
  print l
  return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
  p.imap_unordered(work, sys.stdin.readlines())
```

This is just a test program. In real life, "work" will be replaced by a computationally intensive time consuming process. Since the order of lines doesnt matter, I am trying to use imap_unordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p.imap_unordered()` is an iterator. To advance it, you need to consume it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing
import sys
import time

def work(line):
    time.sleep(len(line))
    return line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(work, sys.stdin):
        sys.stdout.write(result)
```

If `file.txt` contains:

```
ccc
bb
a
```

then the output is:

```
bb
ccc
a
```

If you increase the maximum number of workers from 2 to 3 then the output is:

```
a
bb
ccc
```

To run it, pass input on stdin:

```
$ python mycode.py <file.txt
```

To redirect the output to another file:

```
$ python mycode.py <file.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: How to run the above snippet? I was trying to run the above program with following command python test.py > test.txt  but no output observed.

Comment: @sihrc: no, buffering has nothing to do with it

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Sorry, I guess I'm out of my league here. Curious to see the solution now.

Comment: @SrikanthBhandary: I've added example commands. When `mycode.py` ends; the results are in `output.txt` (if you've used the command with `>output.txt`).